# PHP - if else not working well

Tags: php, if-statement

I try switch statement but still same... now all option i selected are going `$cimb` ... can anyone help me to let them redirect to correct url ?

Following bellow is my coding :

```
$detectpay = mysql_query("select paymethod from themetransaction");
                $showdpay = mysql_fetch_array($detectpay);
                $credit = "Credit Card";
                $cimb = "CIMB Clicks";
                $may = "Maybank2U";
                $paypal = "Paypal";
                $public = "Public eBank";
                $rhb = "RHB Now";
                switch($showdpay['paymethod'])
                    {
                        case $credit:
                            $echo = "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5;url=http://www.facebook.com/' />";
                            break;
                        case $cimb:
                            $echo = "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5;url=https://www.cimbclicks.com.my/ibk/' />";
                            break;
                        case $may:  
                            $echo =  "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5;url=https://www.maybank2u.com.my/mbb/m2u/common/M2ULogin.do?action=Login' />";
                            break;
                        case $paypal:   
                            $echo =  "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5;url=https://www.paypal.com/my/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-submit' />";
                            break;
                        case $public:
                            $echo =  "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5;url=https://www2.pbebank.com/myIBK/apppbb/servlet/BxxxServlet?RDOName=BxxxAuth&MethodName=login' />";
                            break;
                        case $rhb:
                            $echo =  "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5;url=https://logon.rhb.com.my/ />";
                            break;
                        default:
                            $echo = "none of the above worked...";
                    }


                echo $echo;
```

Comment: you need to use a switch statemente there...

Comment: Single `=` is an assignment operator, double `==` is a loose comparison and triple `===` is a strict comparison. You want at least loose comparison (`==`) here. Other than that, you should use a switch statement instead. Main benefit there is that you only have to write the variable name once, instead of 6 times in your example.

Comment: @Matías how to do switch statement ? im very new in php

Comment: @scrowler hi i use before . still the name

Comment: see my answer, it has a link to the documentation

Comment: Can you echo $showdpay['paymethod'] for testing?

Answer (score 3):

Your `if`s needs double equal sign: `==`

```
if($showdpay['paymethod'] == $credit) //and so on...
```

But seeing your code, I should suggest using a [switch](http://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.switch.php) statement.

A little help:

You can rewrite your code from this:

```
if($showdpay['paymethod'] == $credit)
{
    echo " <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5;url=http://www.facebook.com/' />";
}
elseif($showdpay['paymethod'] == $cimb)
{
    echo"<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5;url=https://www.cimbclicks.com.my/ibk/' />";
}
```

to this:

```
switch($showdpay['paymethod'])
{
    case $credit:
        $echo = "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5;url=http://www.facebook.com/' />";
        break;
    case $cimb:
        $echo = "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5;url=https://www.cimbclicks.com.my/ibk/' />";
        break;
    default:
        $echo = "none of the above worked...";
}

echo $echo;
```

Comment: hi i use `==` but still the same

Comment: hi thanks for your answer ~ but all option has become `$cimb` choose any of the selection are going to `$cimb` url

Comment: any idea how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You're assiging with `=` use `==` to compare values

ie `if($showdpay['paymethod'] == $credit)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `==` for comparison. Single `=` is for assigning value in a variable.

```
 if($showdpay['paymethod'] = $credit)
```

should be:

```
 if($showdpay['paymethod'] == $credit)
```

Also change all your if else block.

`if($showdpay['paymethod'] = $credit)` is assigning `$credit to $showdpay['paymethod']` before executing the `if` so PHP  will now read it as `if("Credit Card");` which will return true as always.

**EDIT:** for your query.

```
$detectpay = mysql_query("select paymethod from themetransaction");
```

should be:

```
$detectpay = mysql_query("select paymethod from themetransaction where paymethod = '".$var."'");
```

Wherein `$var` is the one you've chosen in the select-box. Your code will always get Credit Card if Credit Card is the first record in `themetransaction` table.